# Header file is inaccessible

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, header-files

I'm using cocos2d-x to create my project but I'm getting this error:

> Error (active)    "CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::SimpleAudioEngine()"
>   (declared at line 256 of "c:\MyGame
>   \cocos2d\cocos\audio\include\SimpleAudioEngine.h") is
>   inaccessible  MyGame c:\MyGame \Classes\MyGame .cpp

So I am including the SimpleAudioEngine.h file into my CPP file, to work with it. As you can see from the error, to use the SimpleAudioEngine, I need to use the CocosDenshion namespace first, but as soon as I am done typing:

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine()
```

Visual Studio shows this error to me, VS can show me the declaration, so that tells me that it knows where the header is and it can be read. So I don't know what is the issue for being inaccessible. What are some reason for header files to be inaccessible?

> MyGame.cpp

```
#include "MyGame.h"
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#include "GlobalVariables.h"

USING_NS_CC;

Scene* MyGame::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = MyGame::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}

bool MyGame::init()
{
    if (!Layer::init())
    {
        return false;
    }
    is_dragged = false;

    const char* MUSIC_PATH = "Music/Main_Theme_loop.ogg";
    initTouch();
    initTiled();
    tempSetupSprite();

    debugDrawLine();

    this->scheduleUpdate();
    return true;
}
```

> MyGame.h

```
#include "GameSprite.h"
#include "GameMap.h"

class MyGame : public cocos2d::Layer
{
private:
    void update(float dt);
    void initTouch();
    void initTiled();

    void tempSetupSprite();
    void debugDrawLine();
public:
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

    virtual bool init();

    virtual bool onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch* _touch, cocos2d::Event* _event);
    virtual void onTouchEnded(cocos2d::Touch* _touch, cocos2d::Event* _event);
    virtual void onTouchMoved(cocos2d::Touch* _touch, cocos2d::Event* _event);
    virtual void onTouchCancelled(cocos2d::Touch* _touch, cocos2d::Event* _event);

    CREATE_FUNC(MyGame);
private:
    bool is_dragged;

    Vec2 first_touch;
    Vec2 last_drag_touch;

    GameSprite* sprite;
    GameMap* map;
};
```

Comment: it means the default constructor for `SimpleAudioEngine` is either `private` or `protected`.

Comment: Read the error message again. It does not say that the header file is inaccessible; it says that the constructor `CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::SimpleAudioEngine()` is inaccessible (probably it is private).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of cocos2d-x (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.5/de/d8f/class_cocos_denshion_1_1_simple_audio_engine.html). The constructor is protected. You have to use the following method to get the shared static simple audio engine instance:

```
getInstance()
```

Comment: I'm aware of that but Visual Studio won't allow me to call that static function at all. It keeps giving the error I described above.

Comment: @Daniel could you share your cpp file?

Answer (score 0):

Check "cocos2d.h" and you will find that "SimpleAudioEngine.h" is not included here. So you have to include it first when you try to use it.

Locating the header file by VS doesn't mean that the file is accessible in your cpp file. It is just a convenient function provided by VS to let the user easy to check the file.